# Should I use articles before official titles if they do not precede names?

Tags: articles

Should I use articles before official titles if they do not precede names?

For example,

> [name] became PM.

vs

> [name] became **the** PM.

Comment: I think no, but it is more common to use a prefix like Mr/Mrs/Dr or whatever alike before that name in my humble opinion.

Comment: Do you mean '[name] became PM' versus '[name] became the PM'?

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Yes

Comment: Does this help you? [The definite article before a title](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/the-definite-article-before-a-title)

Comment: @AIQ "As an English language learner, [...]" — thanks, not interested. I'm an English learner myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, both forms are correct, so to answer your specific question - you don't have to use the definite article before a title. In fact, I would prefer your first option.  Here are some examples:

> When Obama became president in 2009, Republicans could afford to have former President George W. Bush sit on the sidelines as they rebuilt their strength. ([source](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2018/03/where-is-barack-obama/555296/))
>
> Henry became king more or less immediately in what was the first bloodless transfer of power in England for nearly a century (though his coronation didn’t take place until 24 June 1509). ([source](https://www.historyhit.com/when-was-henry-viii-born-when-did-he-become-king-and-how-long-was-his-reign/))

I'd use the option with "the" if it's followed by "of ...", as in "he became **the** PM **of France**", or "she became **the** queen **of England**".

Comment: But it's not required, is it (regarding your last sentence)?

Comment: In those examples, it's not required. Search for "became queen of England" in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_to_the_British_throne) about, in fact, the British throne.

Comment: You wouldn't, however, say something like "PM of France is here" or "Queen of Spain has just arrived" - you'd put "the" in front of both of those.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only about whether there's a name following the title but also about whether the title denotes the office itself or the officer who holds it.  Your examples show the former case, and I share others' preference for omitting the article, but I'm sure there are native speakers who would include it.

However, you do need the definite article or another determiner when using the name of the office to denote the person holding the office.

> *The* queen sees *the* prime minister weekly.
>
> Some members of the city council want to replace *the* chief of police.

If there are several people holding the same title, though, you might want the indefinite article instead, as in "we are hoping to get *an* ambassador to speak at the conference."

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct.  However, when you use "the", it's understood you may be discussing the specific organization where the person holds the title.